# Implement MSAL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I am working on a Cordova project where we are trying to implement Azure AD authentication using MSAL JS library. I am trying to follow the workflow where in, if user is not yet signed-in we will call popup method otherwise will call the acquire token silently method.   The problem is, every time I refresh the page it always go to the pop-up authentication even though the user is already signed-in. We had implement the same authentication in Xamarin but we never encounter the same problem.

I get this error on acquireTokenSilent

```
The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named 'client'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

Code:

```
async function getTokenPopup(request) {
//request.account = account;
return await myMSALObj
.acquireTokenSilent(request)
.then(function(accessTokenResponse){
    console.log("Access Token", accessTokenResponse.accessToken);
})
.catch(async (error) => {
    console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");
    if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        console.log("acquiring token using popup");
        return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Just save the token in a variable somewhere and test if it exists before fetching it

Comment: @Eric, I am actually doing that already but the problem is, we are implementing single sign on. The expectation is, if the user is already signed-in to other application then he should not enter his credentials again in cordova apps.

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect that, hard to see the issue so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing how I solve my issue for future devs that will encounter the same issue. You need to pass silentRequest object which contains name as hint to be able to use ssoSilent authentication.

```
async function signIn() {
    
    if(isTokenValid()){

        var accounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();

        if(accounts.length === 0 ){
            getTokenPopup(scopeRequest)
                .then(handleSuccessLoginResponse)
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error getting token");
                });
        }
        else{
            silentRequest.loginHint = accounts[0].username;
            handleSilentLogin()
            .then(function(response) {
                handleSuccessLoginResponse(response);
            });
        }
        
    }
   
   
}


async function handleSilentLogin(){
    return myMSALObj.ssoSilent(silentRequest);
}



 async function getTokenPopup(request) {
    return await myMSALObj
    .acquireTokenSilent(request)
    .then(function(accessTokenResponse){
        console.log("Access Token", accessTokenResponse.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(async (error) => {
        console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");
        if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            console.log("acquiring token using popup");
            myMSALObj["browserStorage"].clear();
            return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        } else {
            return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    });
}


function isTokenValid(){

    let tokenFromStorage  = localStorage["msalTokenDetails"];
    if(tokenFromStorage){
        let token = JSON.parse(localStorage["msalTokenDetails"]);

        // check if token expired
        if(token.expiresOn > new Date()){
            // returning false since token is already expired
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
   
}


const silentRequest = {
    loginHint: "IDLAB@msidlab0.ccsctp.net"
};
```